# how to create a list from for loop

Tags: python

everyone, recently I am trying to create a list from my data

Here is my data:

```
!wget --no-check-certificate 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1VfkX_asEXo1HpdSE68Cl_HEdyrKPDxsw' -O /content/API_UAT2.txt
```

I want to find whether these items exist in my data

```
tunnel_fares = {

            'Aberdeen Tunnel':5

                 , 'Lion Rock Tunnel':8

                 , 'Shing Mun Tunnels':5

                 , 'Tseung Kwan O Tunnel':3

                 , 'Tsing Sha Highway':8

                 , 'Cross Harbour Tunnel':20

                 , 'Eastern Harbour Crossing':40

                 , 'Western Harbour Crossing':85

            , 'Tate\'s Cairn Tunnel':20

            , 'Tai Lam Tunnel':48

            , 'Lantau Link':30

            }
```

Here is my code

```
with open ('API_UAT2.txt') as f:  #open the txt
    js = json.load(f) #turns it to json format
    data = js['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']
    for item in data:
      data_name = item['name']
      toll = []
      for name,fare in tunnel_fares.items():
        if name in data_name:
          toll = name
          print(toll)
```

It finally returns

```
Western Harbour Crossing
Tsing Sha Highway
Tsing Sha Highway
```

However, I want to turn it into a list, and remove duplicated object
i.e.:

```
['Western Harbour Crossing', 'Tsing Sha Highway']
```

I tried to use

```
new = list(map(lambda x:x, toll))
```

But it turns out a super weird thing. So how can I do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Code Syntax**

```
with open ('API_UAT2.txt') as f:  #open the txt
    js = json.load(f) #turns it to json format
    data = js['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']
    for item in data:
         data_name = item['name']
         toll = []
         for name,fare in tunnel_fares.items():
              if name in data_name:
                  toll.append(name)
         toll= list(set(toll))

         print(toll)
```

**Output Syntax**

```
['Western Harbour Crossing', 'Tsing Sha Highway']
```

Comment: I am not sure am I correct or not. I copied your code and run it. But it returns `set()`. Thank you

Comment: Check it again, now it's right. When you write `[set(troll)]` this returns **list of set**. But when you use `list(set(troll))` it will convert your list to set then convert the set to list with no duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to do this again. But it returns `[]` this time.

Comment: My fault...hahaha... I'm printing the a list out of the file. Of course, it has to print [].

Comment: @aukk123 check it again for the last time :D

Answer (score 1):

To add an item to a list you would use:

```
toll.append(name)
```

instead of:

```
toll = name
```

Therefore your code will be:

```
with open ('API_UAT2.txt') as f:  #open the txt
    js = json.load(f) #turns it to json format
    data = js['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']
    for item in data:
      data_name = item['name']
      toll = []
      for name,fare in tunnel_fares.items():
        if name in data_name:
          toll.append(name)
          print(toll)
```

Answer (score 1):

Append to a list `toll` and remove duplicates using `dict.fromkeys`:

```
with open ('API_UAT2.txt') as f:  #open the txt
    js = json.load(f) #turns it to json format
    data = js['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']
    for item in data:
      data_name = item['name']
      toll = []
      for name,fare in tunnel_fares.items():
        if name in data_name:
          toll.append(name)

toll = list(dict.fromkeys(toll))
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. However, I tried to do `print(toll)`, and it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a set instead:

```
with open ('API_UAT2.txt') as f:  #open the txt
    js = json.load(f) #turns it to json format
    data = js['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']
    tolls = set()
    for item in data:
      data_name = item['name']
      toll = []
      for name, fare in tunnel_fares.items():
        if name in data_name:
          tolls.add(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

for removing duplicate items from list named l, you can use this code:

```
l = list(set(l))
```